# Documents4j IllegalStateException

Tags: java, pdf, docx, documents4j

im trying to use documents4j (https://bintray.com/raphw/maven/documents4j) in order to convert a docx file to pdf with this code:
Thank you very much in advance, i have no idea of making it works

```
    package documents4j;


import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.documents4j.api.DocumentType;
import com.documents4j.api.IConverter;
import com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter;


public class HelloPDF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File wordFile = new File("c:/datos/Resultados.docx"), target = new File("c:/datos/Resultados.pdf");

        IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder().baseFolder(new File("c:/datos/"))
                .workerPool(20, 25, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .processTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

        Future<Boolean> conversion = converter.convert(wordFile).as(DocumentType.DOCX).to(target).as(DocumentType.PDF)
                // .prioritizeWith(1000) // optional
                .schedule();

    }
}
```

But im encountering an illegalstateexcepcion

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: class com.documents4j.conversion.msoffice.MicrosoftWordBridge could not be created by a (File, long, TimeUnit) constructor
    at com.documents4j.conversion.ExternalConverterDiscovery.make(ExternalConverterDiscovery.java:32)
    at com.documents4j.conversion.ExternalConverterDiscovery.makeAll(ExternalConverterDiscovery.java:42)
    at com.documents4j.conversion.ExternalConverterDiscovery.loadConfiguration(ExternalConverterDiscovery.java:85)
    at com.documents4j.conversion.DefaultConversionManager.<init>(DefaultConversionManager.java:22)
    at com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter.makeConversionManager(LocalConverter.java:79)
    at com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter.<init>(LocalConverter.java:51)
    at com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter$Builder.build(LocalConverter.java:186)
    at documents4j.HelloPDF.main(HelloPDF.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.documents4j.conversion.ExternalConverterDiscovery.make(ExternalConverterDiscovery.java:30)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/documents4j/util/Reaction$IExceptionBuilder
    at com.documents4j.conversion.msoffice.AbstractMicrosoftOfficeBridge.tryStart(AbstractMicrosoftOfficeBridge.java:34)
    at com.documents4j.conversion.msoffice.MicrosoftWordBridge.startUp(MicrosoftWordBridge.java:44)
    at com.documents4j.conversion.msoffice.MicrosoftWordBridge.<init>(MicrosoftWordBridge.java:39)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.documents4j.util.Reaction$IExceptionBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 15 more
[Shutdown hook: com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter] INFO com.documents4j.job.ConverterAdapter - Tried to deregister shut down hook in shut down period
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.remove(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:82)
    at java.lang.Runtime.removeShutdownHook(Runtime.java:237)
    at com.documents4j.job.ConverterAdapter.deregisterShutdownHook(ConverterAdapter.java:121)
    at com.documents4j.job.ConverterAdapter.cleanUp(ConverterAdapter.java:107)
    at com.documents4j.job.ConverterAdapter.shutDown(ConverterAdapter.java:98)
    at com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter.shutDown(LocalConverter.java:109)
    at com.documents4j.job.ConverterAdapter$ConverterShutdownHook.run(ConverterAdapter.java:134)
Exception in thread "Shutdown hook: com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter.shutDown(LocalConverter.java:100)
    at com.documents4j.job.ConverterAdapter$ConverterShutdownHook.run(ConverterAdapter.java:134)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i have found the answer. The problem was that i have not all the libraries included, i add:

documents4j-util-all-1.0.3
documents4j-util-standalone-1.0.3

And it finally works